# nexus 10 remote

Tags: samsung-nexus-10, google-play-movies

I just bought a movie for my nexus 10 on Google play, then I realized I could connect it to my television, the movie looks great but is there anyway I could play/pause the movie remotely? Maybe with my nexus 4?

Comment: the movie is on nexus 10. then the nexus 10 is connected to the tv via hdmi cable is that right?

Comment: That is right ..

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is not with another phone, which would need specialist software for each app you want to control, but with a Bluetooth gamepad such as a PS3 controller. Connect the gamepad to the Nexus 10 using Bluetooth, and then you can use the gamepad to control any app, including Google Play Movies.

"Any app" is a slight exaggeration: some apps might not entirely work properly just with D-pad controls, especially if they have custom controls. But most apps should just work fine, and some have special functionality to make them easier to use with gamepads (such as navigating between screens with the shoulder buttons).

The one thing you might have trouble with is adjusting the volume. Since that's controlled with physical keys, it's hard to get at through the GUI with the D-pad. But if your Nexus 10 is connected to your TV, you can change the volume of the TV with its remote instead.